# How to query multiple table from SqlQuery() method in entity framework 6.0?

Tags: entity-framework

Say I have two table: Table_1 and Table_2,
I want to query the result into `Model`

```
public class Model
{
    public Table_1 table1 { get; set; }
    public Table_2 table2 { get; set; }
}

void Query(Database database)
{
    string sql = @"SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM Table_1 table1 JOIN Table_2 table2 on table1.ID=table2.ParentID";
    var result = database.SqlQuery<Model>(sql).ToArray();
}
```

but these two properties always keep null in result, how can I make them filled? or this is not supported in EF?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot map entities and the relationship between these entities in Entity Framework? The code you have outlined looks like ADO.

Comment: @Steve Py Because query via EF is slow but directly query via script is fast for about 400,000 data in sql server with no reason, I want to found out by comparing.

Comment: What is the EF query that is slow? Have you run a profiler against it an extracted the exact SQL that EF is executing? Writing an SQL statement that you think is equivalent and finding that faster than EF can be useful for comparison, but first you need to inspect exactly what EF is generating in your situation. 99 times out of 100 it doesn't require trying to customize EF's querying, but rather something unexpected happening due to configuration or how you're consuming the entities.